# Calling a private property of a Python instance using a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, getter, getter-setter

I'm somewhat new to OOP in Python (and Python in general), and I'm running into an issue when I try to access an instances private property from within one of the methods, and using a string as the property name.

The goal here is to basically have a list of properties that will be displayed (in a *key - value* format) when the objects getDetails() method is called. And it works fine, as long as all of the properties in the list are not private properties in the object. If all of the properties are *not* private, then it seems to work fine.

In the below example, you can see I have 3 properties, `foo`, `_bar` and `__baz`. In the `TheClass.getDetails()` method, if the `__baz` line is commented out, it works perfectly fine:

```py
class TheClass(object):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.foo   = 'One..'
        self._bar  = 'Two..'
        self.__baz = 'Three..'

    def getDetails( self ):
        display = [ 
            'foo'
            ,'_bar'
            #,'__baz'
        ]

        print "DebugInfo:"
        for key in display:
            print '{0:<15}: {1:<20}'.format(key, self.__dict__[ key ] or 'N/A')

TheClass().getDetails()

""" Output:
DebugInfo:
foo            : One..
_bar           : Two..
"""
```

However, when I uncomment the `__baz` entry in the `display` array, I get an exception thrown:

```
DebugInfo:
foo            : One..
_bar           : Two..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getattr.py", line 18, in <module>
    TheClass().getDetails()
  File "getattr.py", line 16, in getDetails
    print '{0:<15}: {1:<20}'.format(key, self.__dict__[ key ] or 'N/A')
KeyError: '__baz'
```

I tried to change how the property was referenced, switching out the `self.__dict__[ key ]` with `getattr( self, key )`, but that just resulted in the same error:

```
DebugInfo:
foo            : One..
_bar           : Two..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getattr.py", line 18, in <module>
    TheClass().getDetails()
  File "getattr.py", line 16, in getDetails
    print '{0:<15}: {1:<20}'.format( key, getattr( self, key ) or 'N/A')
AttributeError: 'TheClass' object has no attribute '__baz'
```

If I just hardcode the properties, then obviously that will work fine:

```py
class TheClass(object):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.foo   = 'One..'
        self._bar  = 'Two..'
        self.__baz = 'Three..'

    def getDetails( self ):
        print "DebugInfo:"
        print '{0:<15}: {1:<20}'.format( 'foo', self.foo or 'N/A')
        print '{0:<15}: {1:<20}'.format( '_bar', self._bar or 'N/A')
        print '{0:<15}: {1:<20}'.format( '__baz', self.__baz or 'N/A')

TheClass().getDetails()

""" Output:
DebugInfo:
foo            : One..
_bar           : Two..
__baz          : Three..
"""
```

But I need this to be a bit more dynamic. So does anyone know if a way to get this working?

Thanks!

**P.S.** I'm using **Python 2.7.11**

Answer (score 2):

Attributes with a double underscore (e.g. `__foo`) are [mangled](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) to make it harder to access them. The rules are as follows:

> Since there is a valid use-case for class-private members (namely to avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses), there is limited support for such a mechanism, called name mangling. Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs within the definition of a class.

Therefore, in the lookup table, you'd need to look for the symbol `_TheClass__baz` instead of just `__baz`.

Answer (score 1):

double underscores invoke python [name-mangling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references):

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.__private = 1
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> vars(f)
{'_Foo__private': 1}
```

You can see that it changed `__property` to `_<classname>__property`.

Generally speaking, the reason python does this mangling is to allow the programmer to avoid conflicts with subclasses classes that might want to define a method with the same name (but not override the method in the base class).  So, that's when you *should* use double-underscore prefixed attributes.  If you don't have that situation, then you're probably better off just using single underscores (it's more idiomatic).